# How can I change the default port of Remote Desktop (VNC)?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

Let's say I went to:

```
 System > Preferences > Remote Desktop
```

And enable Remote Desktop.  Now let's say I have another machine on the network that is also running a VNC server.  I want to VNC into my network from the outside, but I need each VNC server to be running on different ports.

How can I change Ubuntu's default port for Remote Desktop/VNC?

Comment: you seem to have some confusion about networking here. why do two different VNC services on different computers need to be running on different ports?

Comment: @Sparr Because my router port forwards by port number to a specific local IP address. e.g. 5600 could be 192.168.1.100, 5601 could be to 192.168.1.101. So coming in, it could be mydomain.com:5600 -> 192.168.1.100:5600 or mydomain.com:5601 -> 192.168.1.100:5601

Comment: what model router? you should be able to tell it what the local port for each outside port is. so mydomain.com:5600 -> 192.168.1.100:5600 and mydomain.com:5601 -> 192.168.1.200:5600

Comment: @Sparr Buffalo WZR-HP-g300nh running ddwrt, I just use Port Range Forwarding, so it directly forwards the external IP port to the internal IP address, which is fine by me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a little information from the (now dead) Dave's Tech Blog, you can adjust the port setting by going into `gconf-editor`.

Under `desktop > gnome > remote access` there is a key that says `alternative_port` and is set to `5900`.  Just change the value to what you need.  Then enable the key `use_alternative_port`.

The other option is if your router/firewall support uPnp you can adjust Vino to make the adjustment in the same section of `gconf-editor`.

- Reference: [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this from the command line.
For example, to use port 5555, you would use these two commands:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/use_alternative_port true
gconftool-2 --set --type=int /desktop/gnome/remote_access/alternative_port 5555
```

Note, if you follow the schema docs, the port should be in the 5000 - 50000 range:

> [the alternative_port key is set to] the port which
>   the server will listen to if the 
>   'use_alternative_port' key is set to
>   true. Valid values are in the range
>   from 5000 to 50000.

Answer (score 0):

Under desktop > gnome > remote access there is a key that says alternative_port and is set to 5900. ...of course to do this you need that key to actually exist