# Change the VNC Server Port on Ubuntu

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

Currently VNC Server is running on port 5901.

I want to change the port to be around 10000-10100 (in this range).

How can I do that?

---

I have already tried the suggestions from [How can I change the default port of Remote Desktop (VNC)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8402/148451):

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/use_alternative_port true
gconftool-2 --set --type=int /desktop/gnome/remote_access/alternative_port 10050
```

since I want VNCServer to listen on port 10050 — but that doesn't make any change in the functionality.

Comment: What is the exact type of VNC you're running? Is it TigerVNC/RealVNC/TightVNC/etc.?

Comment: @Yaron I installed `vnc4server`. That works fine on port 5901.

Comment: I think it's because the Ubuntu developers switch to TigerVNC by default, the following Arch user guide should walk you through: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC

Comment: @Yaron Should the same field (`alternative_port`) work for TigerVNC?

Comment: No, that's especially for GSettings and possibly for older versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Yaron So, what's the solution for using a different port on the new versions...?

Comment: LOL, the one I sent in the link, you can specify the port in `/etc/systemd/system/*.socket` (I'm not sure how this service is called on your system) and change the line which starts with `ListenStream=`.

Comment: @Yaron There is no `.socket` file in that directory...

Comment: Yeah, possibly, can you please take a look at `vncconfig`, there's an `-rfbport` option: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/Xvnc4.1.html